# Ubuntu internet connected but won't access pages

Tags: 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and installed ndiswrapper with my driver for my wna3100 usb stick so I can work internet because I have no ethernet on my laptop, stupid, I know. Once I got it installed it worked for maybe 5 to 10 minutes and now it won't load pages in Firefox and it won't work with sudo apt-get update... says unable to reach destination. I have no way to upload code from commands but I will do my best.

Route -n  looks normal with 0.0.0.0 listed first with gateway 192.168.0.1 and Genmask of quad 0's, flag of ug metric 0 ref. 0 use 0 and interface wlan0....then 192.168.0.0 with quad 0's as gateway and Genmask of 255.255.255.0, flag U, metric 9, ref. 0, use 0, and interface wlan0...

Any help is appreciated and I'll try to find a way to post codes of commands.